# Android Database with MySQL Where Clause

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm new in Android Programming, and I'm stuck in a middle of SQL query with Where condition. I want to store my data from database into an arraylist. But my script's always fail with Error message. Anyone have a clue? Thanks before

SearchActivity.java

```java
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup radiosexGroup;
    private RadioButton radiosexButton;
    public SeekBar seekBar;
    public ArrayList<detailKosan> listKosan = new ArrayList<>();

    int progress;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.133/php_kukelkos/search_kosan.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_KOSAN = "arrayKosan";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAMAKOS = "namaKosan";
    private static final String TAG_ALAMAT = "alamat";
    private static final String TAG_SEX = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_TLP = "tlp";
    private static final String TAG_HARGA = "harga";
    private static final String TAG_KAMAR = "jmlKamar";
    private static final String TAG_FASILITAS = "fasilitas";
    private static final String TAG_KET = "keterangan";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray arrayKosan = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        textView.setText("Rp 0 - Rp 0");
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progresValue * 500000;
                textView.setText("Rp 0 - Rp " + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                textView.setText("Rp 0 - Rp " + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

        //Fungsi Button Search
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                searchKosan();
                Intent menuSearch = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ListKosanActivity.class);
                startActivity(menuSearch);
                finish();
            }
        });

    public void searchKosan (){
        int selected = radiosexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radiosexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
        String buttonradio = radiosexButton.getText().toString();
        String msg = "";
        String keyval[][]= {{"harga", String.valueOf(progress)},{"gender", buttonradio}};
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> asycn = new myAsyncData(SearchActivity.this, keyval, "Loading...");
        asycn.execute(url);
        String data = "";
        boolean state = false;

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = null;
            try {
                data = asycn.get().toString();
            } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jobj = new JSONObject(data);
                msg = jobj.getString("message").toString();
                state = jobj.getBoolean("state");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                arrayKosan = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_KOSAN);

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into Arraylist_detail
                 **/
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayKosan.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject c = arrayKosan.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(TAG_ID);
                        String namaKosan = c.getString(TAG_NAMAKOS);
                        String alamat = c.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);
                        String sex = c.getString(TAG_SEX);
                        String tlp = c.getString(TAG_TLP);
                        int harga = c.getInt(TAG_HARGA);
                        String kamar = c.getString(TAG_KAMAR);
                        String fasilitas = c.getString(TAG_FASILITAS);
                        String ket = c.getString(TAG_KET);
                        String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                        Double latt = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                        String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);
                        Double lngg = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                        LatLng PosisiMarker = new LatLng(latt, lngg);

                        listKosan.add(new detailKosan(id, namaKosan, alamat, sex, tlp, harga, kamar, fasilitas, ket, latt, lngg));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String title = (!state) ? "Error" : "Success";

        if(title.equals("Success")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ListKosanActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
            b.setTitle(title);
            b.setMessage(msg);
            b.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", null);
            AlertDialog a = b.create();
            a.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my .php file

```php
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    $response = array();

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $harga  = $_POST["harga"];
    $gender     = $_POST["gender"];
    $fasilitas  = $_POST["fasilitas"];

    if(!empty($harga)&&!empty($gender)) {
        $ins= mysql_query("SELECT * from tbkosan where harga <='".$harga."' and gender = '".$gender"'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($ins> 0) {
        $response["state"] = true;      
        $response["message"] = "Success";
        $response["arrayKosan"] = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ins)) {
            // temp user array
            $dataa= array();
            $dataa["id"] = $row["id"];
            $dataa["namaKosan"] = $row["namaKosan"];
            $dataa["alamat"] = $row["alamat"];
            $dataa["gender"] = $row["gender"];
            $dataa["tlp"] = $row["tlp"];
            $dataa["harga"] = $row["harga"];
            $dataa["jmlKamar"] = $row["jmlKamar"];
            $dataa["fasilitas"] = $row["fasilitas"];
            $dataa["keterangan"] = $row["keterangan"];
            $dataa["lat"] = $row["lat"];
            $dataa["lng"] = $row["lng"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($result["arrayKosan"], $dataa);  
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Data tidak ada";
        }
    }
    else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Harap isi data search terlebih dulu!";
    echo json_encode($result);
    }
}


?>
```

and this is my ServiceHandler.java

```java
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

and the result is :
alert box with no message, and dissmiss button (sorry i cant post a pic hehe)

Comment: Your PHP/query has [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) in it.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging here. Is the PHP API being called? If it is, have you examined its raw output on the Java side?

Comment: @halfer yeah i know its weak againts SQL injection, but I'm not focus on it. I haven't examined it's raw output in java, and i dont know how to do it in android studio. i need to do it in my device

Comment: Not sure, only a PHP dev, so can't help with Java. Have you checked the page has run successfully on the PHP side? You can write debug info to a file at the end of the PHP script, and if this doesn't get written at all, you'll know either the script doesn't finish, or it isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("SELECT * from tbkosan where harga <='$harga' and gender='$gender'");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem AS THIS one of yours i have chosen to use volley library on android part where it helped me to pass input variable to php where clause
 refer to this post and check the answer:

[How to parse multiple rows with jsonOject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330098/how-to-parse-multiple-rows-with-jsonoject/45330447?noredirect=1#comment77641602_45330447)

or follow the followithing tutorial watch function called  **function StoreUserInfo** and refer to second part to activity called **RegisterActivity.java** these can help you to fetch using where clause:

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/androidwithphp/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql/