# How to parse multiple rows with jsonOject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am fetching data from **mysql** using **php** API and i pass results to android with `Json_encode` but when i populate results to android listview i get only one first row.

This is reuslt i am getting on web :
`{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration":"59min","parking_name":"asass"}}
{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"100","parking_duration":"22min","parking_name":"SDSDASDAS"}}`

PHP part :

```
                       ...........
                      $usersArr = $db->getDriverHistory($plate_no);
           if ($usersArr != false) {
          foreach($usersArr as $key=>$user){
            // use is found
          $response[$key]["error"] = FALSE;
             $response[$key]["user"]["paid_amount"] = $user["paid_amount"];
             $response[$key]["user"]["parking_duration"] = 
          $user["parking_duration"];
        $response[$key]["user"]["parking_name"] = $user["parking_name"];
      $response = $response[$key] ;
         // echo json_encode($response), "<br>";
        // echo $response;        
          $json = json_encode($response);
          echo $json,"<br>";
             ......
```

Android code : what i need is to get all results where plate number equals to some number but i am getting only one row instead of all rows .

```
                 private void GetParkingInfo(final String plate_no) {
               // Tag used to cancel the request
       String tag_string_req = "req_Verfication";

       progressBarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           //        myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Urls.URL_driver_parking_information, new 
         Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cerfication Response: " + response.toString());             
            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                 try {

                     JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {


                        // user successfully exist in database
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String paid_amount = user.getString("paid_amount");
                        String parking_duration = 
               user.getString("parking_duration");
                        String parking_name = user.getString("parking_name");
                        HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new 
                    HashMap<String, String>();

                        prodHashMap.put("paid_amount", paid_amount);
                        prodHashMap.put("parking_duration", parking_duration);
                        prodHashMap.put("parking_name", parking_name);

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                           wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        wordList.add(prodHashMap);
                        userList = wordList ;
                        ShowListData();

                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                         }

                      else{

                        // Error in login. Get the error message
              //                       // hiding the progress bar
                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, 
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + 
             e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //                     // hiding the progress bar
                    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                }
            }
              }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Verfication error Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        //                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // hiding the progress bar
            progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
             }) {
            @Override
             protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            // Posting parameters to verfication url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("plate_no", plate_no);
            return params;
           }
        };
    //        // Adding request to request queue

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq,tag_string_req);
       }
```

Comment: I'm reading your post and I see many unclear things and **why you do `echo $json,"<br>";`** :). Okay I guess also that your json data is array `[]`, correct? Because I see only two js objects with the same structure ... You need to parse the json before the loop in the Android part. Finally please make some efforts to format your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting just one row, you're creating a new ArrayList through every iteration.  You'll only ever get the last row this way.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                       wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

You need to initialize your list outside your for loop.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

    // add your information here
}
```

Edit::

I see what's happening.  You're looping for the length of String.  You need to convert your String response to a JSONArray and loop through that.  This way you step through each JSONObject in the array

```
        List<HashMap<String, String>> wordList = new 
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        try {
           JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                // get user // do rest of work
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit 2::

This should get you going.  I haven't tested, so watch out for any missing brackets.

```
    private void GetParkingInfo(final String plate_no) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_Verfication";

    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //        myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Urls.URL_driver_parking_information, new
            Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "cerfication Response: " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        if (jsonArray != null && !jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (!jsonObject.isNull("user")) {
                                    JSONObject user = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user");
                                    String paid_amount = user.getString("paid_amount");
                                    String parking_duration =
                                            user.getString("parking_duration");
                                    String parking_name = user.getString("parking_name");
                                    HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new
                                            HashMap<String, String>();

                                    prodHashMap.put("paid_amount", paid_amount);
                                    prodHashMap.put("parking_duration", parking_duration);
                                    prodHashMap.put("parking_name", parking_name);

                                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                                    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                    wordList.add(prodHashMap);
                                    userList = wordList ;
                                    ShowListData();

                                    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " +
                                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //                     // hiding the progress bar
                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Verfication error Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            //                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // hiding the progress bar
            progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            // Posting parameters to verfication url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("plate_no", plate_no);
            return params;
        }
    };
    //        // Adding request to request queue

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq,tag_string_req);
}
```

Edit 3::

```
if ($usersArr != false) { 
    foreach($usersArr as $user){
        $subresponse["error"] = FALSE; 
        $subresponse["user"]["paid_amount"] = $user["paid_amount"];
        $subresponse["user"]["parking_duration"] = $user["parking_duration"]; 
        $subresponse["user"]["parking_name"] = $user["parking_name"];
        $response[] = $subresponse;
        $json = json_encode($response);
```

how I think it should look

```
  if ($usersArr != false) { 
       foreach($usersArr as $user){
           $subresponse["error"] = FALSE; 
           $subresponse["user"]["paid_amount"] = $user["paid_amount"];
           $subresponse["user"]["parking_duration"] = $user["parking_duration"]; 
           $subresponse["user"]["parking_name"] = $user["parking_name"];
           $response[] = $subresponse;
      } 
      $json = json_encode($response);
```

Comment: With this trick of yours is only first row which repeats itself to infinity . I guess i may add ArrayList to loop response instead of JsonObject

Comment: , It could be , but not because on web i have two rows , but to android part when i use your way or @Reena's user way i get only the following first row which repeats several times . row i get : `{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration":"59min","parking_name":"asass"}}`

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  There must be something else going on. What does ShowListData(); do, exactly?

Comment: is the methoth to add `userList` data to ListView. nothing else which is going on , is only that JSonObject is getting the first row only and is unable to jump to the next row . where  `wordList` is  an array list used to parse any JsonObject gotten to the ListView

Comment: I have edited my answer to solve your problem.  There were a few problems at work here.

Comment: thank you but i'm not familiar with JsonArray please edit my whole android part , because with my edit i'm getting an error ; Json error : `vaue  {"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration‌​":"59min","parking_n‌​ame":"asass"}}  of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSonArray`

Comment: i am getting the same error : `{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration‌​":"59min","parking_n‌​ame":"asass"}}`

Comment: I'm only so skilled in the php realm.  Try replacing "json_encode($response);" with "json_encode(array($response));".

Comment: Wait... Is your site only returning a single object at a time?  In your OP you showed that the service was returning {...}{...}{...}.  Now it seems that you're calling new JSONArray() on a string with only one json object in it...

Comment: you'are right , but the site returns all two rows as i have it , but to android side i get only one

Comment: i replaced "json_encode($response);" with "json_encode(array($response));  and i think this can be a good solution the problem is that the output seem not to be  read by JsonArray. out upt is like this : `[{"error":false,"user":{first row result}}][{"error":false,"user":{second row result}}]`

Comment: We need your output from the server to look like so: [{"error":false,"user":{...}}, {"error":false,"user":{...}}]. I can dig deeper into this tomorrow for you

Comment: I added code that will return an array for you. But I don't understand why you're encoding for each iteration. You should be doing it at the end when you return all results.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and abondant ideas i finally solved the issue , the problem was that my server side used to output json objects which can not be looped in java. and another problem i was encoding to each iteration

Comment: Those are both of the problems this answer addresses... 
No problem. Glad I could help =)

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized collection in wrong place, Please have look at following code this may help you

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
            wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {


                        // user successfully exist in database
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String paid_amount = user.getString("paid_amount");
                        String parking_duration =
                                user.getString("parking_duration");
                        String parking_name = user.getString("parking_name");
                        HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new
                                HashMap<String, String>();

                        prodHashMap.put("paid_amount", paid_amount);
                        prodHashMap.put("parking_duration", parking_duration);
                        prodHashMap.put("parking_name", parking_name);


                        wordList.add(prodHashMap);
                        ;

                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                    userList = wordList ;
                    ShowListData()
```

Comment: With this  way of yours is only first row which repeats itself to infinity . I guess i may add ArrayList to loop response instead of JsonObject

Answer (score 0):

This solution will help anyone who needds to fetch data from mysql using where clause based to android input with volley library .

DBHandler which handles php functions :

```
                     .....
               public function getDriverHistory($plate_no) {
             $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from drivers_history 
           where  drivers_history.plate_no = ?");

          $stmt->bind_param("s", $plate_no);
           if ($stmt->execute()) {

           //  $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();       
           //  $stmt->close();
           // return $user;

         $result = $stmt->get_result();
          $usersArr = array();
         while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $usersArr[] = $user;
         }
          $stmt->close();
         return $usersArr;


         } else {
        return NULL;
         }
         }
             ....
```

GetdriverFunction.php used to access function above :

```
                                      ...........

           <?php
               include './DbHandler.php';
              $db = new DBHandler(); 
          // json response array
        $response = array("error" => FALSE); 
            if (isset($_POST['plate_no'])) {
              // receiving the post params
                 $plate_no = $_POST['plate_no']; 
                  $usersArr = $db->getDriverHistory($plate_no);
              if ($usersArr != false) {
            $response["error"]= FALSE;
          $response["user"] = $usersArr;
         echo json_encode($response); 
              }
             }
         ......
```

finally Java part method to fetch all results where plate_no equals to something plate_no :

```
              private void GetParkingInfo(final String plate_no) {
           // Tag used to cancel the request
             String tag_string_req = "req_Verfication";

   progressBarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //        myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        Urls.URL_driver_parking_information, new 
     Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "cerfication Response: " + response.toString());             
        // Parsing json
        JSONArray jsonArrayResult ;
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

             try {

                 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {


                    // user successfully exist in database

                      jsonArrayResult = jObj.getJSONArray("user");

                for(int x=0; x<jsonArrayResult.length();x++){

                     JSONObject json = jsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(x);


                    String paid_amount = json.getString("paid_amount");
                    String parking_duration = 
           json.getString("parking_duration");
                    String parking_name = json.getString("parking_name");
                    HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new 
                HashMap<String, String>();

                    prodHashMap.put("paid_amount", paid_amount);
                    prodHashMap.put("parking_duration", parking_duration);
                    prodHashMap.put("parking_name", parking_name);

                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                       wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    wordList.add(prodHashMap);
                    userList = wordList ;
                    }
                    ShowListData();

                    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     }

                  else{

                    // Error in login. Get the error message
          //                       // hiding the progress bar
                    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + 
         e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                     // hiding the progress bar
                progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
            }
        }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Verfication error Error: " + error.getMessage());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    //                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // hiding the progress bar
        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
         }) {
        @Override
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

        // Posting parameters to verfication url
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("plate_no", plate_no);
        return params;
       }
    };
//        // Adding request to request queue

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq,tag_string_req);
   }
```